# What is the science behind the polar light shapes

Tags: light, aurora, corona

Is there any scientific explanation that causes polar lights (aurora borealis/australis) to have their unique shapes?

Specifically:

1. Rayed Arcs
2. Dual Bands
3. Corona

(Images on NASA Pdf)

This site (by NASA) proposes:

> The different shapes of auroras are a mystery that scientists are still trying to 
>   unravel. The shape seems to depend on where in the magnetosphere the electrons 
>   originate, what causes them to gain their energy, and why they dive into the 
>   atmosphere.

(Subsection: Why do auroras come in different colors and shapes?)

I am specifically asking if there are any scientific observations (formulas or even simulations) that could describe such patterns (or even similar observations from fluid or gas dynamics). Furthermore, if it forms a rippled ring for instance, there should be a wave-like function, right?

Afterall, they could also be in a straight line..

[Aurora - NASA Pdf](https://pwg.gsfc.nasa.gov/polar/EPO/auroral_poster/aurora_all.pdf)

Comment: Can you add links please? Specifically to the images and 'this site'.

Comment: Oops, my bad. I wanted to add it but forgot. Editing.

Comment: Sounds like a really messy collection of nonlinear fluid flow and magnetic force-line equations.

Comment: But afterall it doesn't look soo messy (if you look at the rayed arcs). It almost looks like the glowlines are well alligned

Comment: Are there even such things as "plasma dynamics"? Overall the aurora is just of type "cold plasma".

Comment: If after a while there's no luck here, you could consider moving your question to [Earth Science SE](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/) instead. I'll post a link in their chat room now.