# Have auroras on Titan been observed yet?

Tags: planetary-atmosphere, titan, aurora

After reading the very insightful [introduction to auroras on other planets](https://aurorareykjavik.is/2020/07/13/auroras_on_other_planets/) I started digging and found various questions and some answers here on the same topic, see below.

What I did not figure out yet: **Have auroras been observed on the moon [Titan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titan_%28moon%29)?**

I am aware that Titan does not have a significant magnetic field, but to my understanding that would only mean that the aurora would occur right at the impact point of solar winds rather than in polar regions, given that the particle flow is enough intense.

#### References

- [Comprehensive intro to Titan by phys.org](https://phys.org/news/2015-10-saturn-moon-titan.html)
- [What would Aurora look like if no magnetic field was present around the Earth?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/38810/what-would-aurora-look-like-if-no-magnetic-field-was-present-around-the-earth)
- [What is the science behind the polar light shapes](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/24329/what-is-the-science-behind-the-polar-light-shapes)
- [Why is Ganymede's aurora only visible in ultraviolet while Earth's is bright green and red?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/34722/why-is-ganymedes-aurora-only-visible-in-ultraviolet-while-earths-is-bright-gre)

Comment: I could be wrong, but I would imagine that since there isn’t a magnetic field to kind of organize the particles, that the random interaction of charged particles with the atmosphere would be so diffuse as to not produce a sustained, readily apparent effect

Comment: @uhoh Thanks for offering the bounty. I am indeed interested still, although currently being a bit quiet in general.

Comment: @B--rian Sure! I hope all is well and being quiet is good; I think the question is quite interesting and well-researched. It may require attention from real planetary scientist, so I've [pinged](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/30323/is-there-an-absolute-limit-to-single-stage-%e2%88%86v-when-tank-mass-is-a-fixed-faction#comment199792_30324) Tom Spilker in Space SE.